# Is there a way to dynamically specify an array in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Yesterday, I found this example of data and some array formulas:

[image]

The idea is to use a formula to calculate the number of employees in Departments A and B combined.

One solution offered was to use an array function to sum the result of IF formulas like this:

```
{=SUM(IF(A2:A9=C2,B2:B9,0),IF(A2:A9=C3,B2:B9,0))}
```

This gives 16 if the criteria are A and B and will give different results if you change the letters under Criteria.

Another solution was to put the criteria into an array constant and use this array function:

```
{=SUM(IF(A2:A9={"A","B"},B2:B9,0))}
```

So, naturally, what I want to do is to be able to use this simpler construction but not have to hard-code the array constant. Something along the lines of:

```
{=SUM(IF(A2:A9=C2:C3,B2:B9,0))}
```

or

```
{=SUM(IF(A2:A9=INDIRECT("C2:C3"),B2:B9,0))}
```

But neither of those works.

It looks like it has something to do with the different sizes of the arrays because if I change the data thus:

[image]

and then use this formula (notice that the comparison "array" is now the same size), it gives the correct answer:

```
{=SUM(IF(A2:A9=C2:C9,B2:B9,0))}
```

But that, obviously, is not a good way to establish criteria.

Is there a way to substitute for the array constant something that refers to the two cells containing the critiera?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple sumifs should do here if I am gauging the request right.

[image]

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to solve the problem of how many employees are in A and B. The question was whether there is a way to use an *array formula* that *dynamically* refers to C2:C3 (the range in the original example) instead of hard-coding an array constant. But thanks for your answer.